# How do I use Conll 2003 corpus in python crfsuite

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, crfsuite, python-crfsuite

I have downloaded Conll 2003 corpus ("eng.train"). I want to use it to extract entity using python crfsuite training. But I don't know how to load this file for training.

I found this example, but it is not for English.

```
train_sents = list(nltk.corpus.conll2002.iob_sents('esp.train'))
test_sents = list(nltk.corpus.conll2002.iob_sents('esp.testb'))
```

Also in future I would like to train new entities other than POS or location. How can I add those.

Also please suggest how to handle multiple words.

Comment: having the same problem. Seems you'd have to write a parser that produces the same output for English as the example you mentioned does for Spanish. Were you able to find an easier path?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ConllCorpusReader**.

**Here a general impelemantation**:
`ConllCorpusReader('file path', 'file name', columntypes=['','',''])`

**Here a list of column types which you can use**: `'WORDS', 'POS', 'TREE', 'CHUNK', 'NE', 'SRL', 'IGNORE'`

**Example**:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import ConllCorpusReader

train = ConllCorpusReader('CoNLL-2003', 'eng.train', ['words', 'pos', 'ignore', 'chunk'])
test = ConllCorpusReader('CoNLL-2003', 'eng.testa', ['words', 'pos', 'ignore', 'chunk'])
```